# Edge browser - cookies not removed

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, microsoft-edge

Our application  is based on java code which is depolyed as wqar files and loaded by Apach/Weblogic. After the user is authenticated we create cookies and check for those cookies later to make sure he doesn't need to be authenticated again when opening a new tab (cookies also have time limit). We have few issues:

We don't see the cookies we created in the cookies section of Edge although the application (java code) clearly get the cookie when it checks for exisiting cookies.

After restarting Edge our application is letting the user connect with no authentication. This also happenes if I set Edge to remove cookies after closing the browser.

Issue persistes even if I use the remove all cookies of Edge. I also noticed other company applications have similar behavior regarding the cookies still persist after restarting Edge (although unlike our cookies I can see the other application cookies).

This issue is not hapenning in Firfox and Chrome. Something in the way Edge is handling the cookies keeps them active somehow even you manually remove all cookies in the settings and you don't see any cookies before you close the browser.

Thank you,

Amir

Tried:

removing all cookies
setting edge to remove cookies when closed

Application still identifies the cookies and not asking for authenticastion.

Comment: Does this issue only occur to 1 device? If so, you can try resetting Edge or even re-installing Edge. If this issue occurs to more than 1 device, you can check whether Edge Dev or Edge Canary also has such issue.